# Make change multiple times on a single click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get JavaScript to change text multiple times in a single click, then go back to the original text.  I can get the text to change, but not change automatically to another piece of text, or change back to the original text.

So the text would go from "original text" to "text 1" to "text 2" to "text 3" etc for as many as I need, then it would go back to "original text"

He's the current code I have so far

```
function changeText() { 
    document.getElementById('changingtext').innerHTML = 'text 1';
    setTimeout("changeText()",3000);
}
```

And here's the html

```
<p id="changingtext" onclick="changeText()">original text</p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind passing arguments to your function:

```js
function changeText(new_text) {  
  var original_text = document.getElementById('changingtext').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('changingtext').innerHTML = new_text;
  setTimeout("changeText('"+original_text+"')",3000);
}
```

```html
<p id="changingtext" onclick="changeText('text 1')">original text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses an array of texts to cycle through, adding the original text as the last item in that array.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n75x4qyj/3/)

**Javascript**

```
var changeTexts = ['text 1','text 2','text 3','text 4','text 5'];

function changeText(index) {     
  var element = document.getElementById('changingtext');

  if(index >= changeTexts.length){
    changeTexts.splice(-1,1);
    return;
  }

  if(index === 0) changeTexts.push(element.innerHTML);   

  element.innerHTML = changeTexts[index];
  index++;

  setTimeout(function(){ changeText(index); },1000);    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="changingtext" onclick="changeText(0)">original text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```js
var originalText,
    messages = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3'],
    currentItem = 0;

function changeText() {  
  // capture the original text 
  originalText = originalText || document.getElementById('changingtext').innerHTML;

  // get element 
  var elem = document.getElementById('changingtext');

  // Check if we hit the last message
  // if so, go back to original and stop 
  if (currentItem >= messages.length) {
      elem.innerHTML = originalText;
  } else {
      elem.innerHTML = messages[currentItem++];
      setTimeout("changeText()", 3000);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="changingtext" onclick="changeText()">original text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is that you call the function `changeText` on both the click and the `timeout` and that function changes the text so on both the click and after the `timeout` you set the text to the same hardcoded value in the `changeText` function.

The best solution to that is, as both IrkenInvader and Uzbekjon have already answered (at the time of writing), is to add a parameter to your `changeText` function to allow for more customization. My javascript would be a tiny bit different than both, but that's more of a preference than a better solution per se, however, I will post my javascript for another reason. The resaon being that you are using `setTimeout` with a string, which is the same as using `eval` and that is a big no-no for many reasons, as explained in [this article](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) and many many **many** other ones you can easily find on Google.

For this reason I recommend this combination:

```js
function changeText(new_text) {
  var original_text = document.getElementById('changingtext').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('changingtext').innerHTML = new_text;
  if (original_text != new_text) {
    setTimeout(changeText.bind(this, original_text), 3000);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="changingtext" onclick="changeText('text 1')">original text</p>
```

You can see here that `function.bind` is used and this is passed as first parameter. This skips using `eval` and still is able to pass function arguments to the `func` specified in `setTimeout` while retaining cross-browser compatibility. Past IE 9, you can also use

```
setTimeout(changeText, 3000, original_text);
```

so if you don't need IE 9 or below, that's much cleaner.